# Selenium-3.0 and Python 2.7 Installed But No Module Error

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, importerror

I have tried everything I found here at Stackoverflow. I have run out of options. What is wrong?

```
Praysons-MacBook-Pro:pyChrome praysondaniel$ pip install -U selenium
Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.0.0b3-py2.7.egg

Praysons-MacBook-Pro:pyChrome praysondaniel$ python
Python 2.7.10 (v2.7.10:15c95b7d81dc, May 23 2015, 09:33:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from selenium import webdriver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named selenium
>>>
```

I have tried all other suggestion here including This [ImportError: No module named 'selenium'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147660/importerror-no-module-named-selenium).

```
>>> import sys; sys.path
['', '/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-override', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override', '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
>>>
```

Comment: what does the following python command `import sys;  sys.path` say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named 'selenium'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147660/importerror-no-module-named-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I came about is by creating a [virtual Environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). Within my virtual environment, I pip install -U selenium and walla! It works