# Python : no module named selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

After searching the web for hours i didnt yet find an answer to my problem. I am using Python 3.6 and i cant import selenium. I always get the message "No module named 'selenium''
I tried everything, i first downloaded selenium from this website https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium/3.6.0 .

Then I tried python -m pip install -U selenium and didnt work either. I tried some other things that people said but they didnt work either.
Im using windows 10.
Any help?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584241/trouble-installing-selenium-for-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble installing selenium for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584241/trouble-installing-selenium-for-python)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/baijum/1047207/33b3ac998e30e967318b14dc1db1f1d687c34d5d says, "Python 3 is not yet supported."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned you are `using Python 3.6` following the steps :

- Open `Command Line Interface` (`CLI`) and issue the command `python` to check if Python is properly installed  :

  ```
  C:\Users\username>python
  Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Jan 16 2018, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
   on win32
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>>
  ```
- Ensure `pip` is working properly :

  ```
  C:\Users\username>pip

  Usage:
    pip <command> [options]

  Commands:
    install                     Install packages.
    download                    Download packages.
    uninstall                   Uninstall packages.
    freeze                      Output installed packages in requirements format.
    list                        List installed packages.
    show                        Show information about installed packages.
    check                       Verify installed packages have compatible dependencies.
    search                      Search PyPI for packages.
    wheel                       Build wheels from your requirements.
    hash                        Compute hashes of package archives.
    completion                  A helper command used for command completion.
    help                        Show help for commands.

  General Options:
    -h, --help                  Show help.
    --isolated                  Run pip in an isolated mode, ignoring environment variables and user configuration.
    -v, --verbose               Give more output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.
    -V, --version               Show version and exit.
    -q, --quiet                 Give less output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times (corresponding to WARNING, ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).
    --log <path>                Path to a verbose appending log.
    --proxy <proxy>             Specify a proxy in the form [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.
    --retries <retries>         Maximum number of retries each connection should attempt (default 5 times).
    --timeout <sec>             Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds).
    --exists-action <action>    Default action when a path already exists: (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup, (a)bort.
    --trusted-host <hostname>   Mark this host as trusted, even though it does not have valid or any HTTPS.
    --cert <path>               Path to alternate CA bundle.
    --client-cert <path>        Path to SSL client certificate, a single file containing the private key and the certificate in PEM format.
    --cache-dir <dir>           Store the cache data in <dir>.
    --no-cache-dir              Disable the cache.
    --disable-pip-version-check
                                Don't periodically check PyPI to determine
                                whether a new version of pip is available for
                        download. Implied with --no-index.
  ```
- Install latest `selenium` through `pip` :

  ```
  C:\Users\username>pip install -U selenium
  Collecting selenium
    Downloading selenium-3.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (931kB)
      100% |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 942kB 322kB/s
  Installing collected packages: selenium
  Successfully installed selenium-3.8.1
  ```
- Confirm that `Selenium` is installed :

  ```
  C:\Users\username>pip freeze
  selenium==3.8.1
  ```
- Open an `IDE` (e.g `Eclipse`, `PyCharm`) and write a simple program as follows :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe")
  driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
  ```
- Execute the program on which `Firefox Quantum` Browser will be initiated and the `url` **`https://stackoverflow.com`** will be accessed.

---

### Python Download Location (Windows) :

Python (for Windows) can be download from the following location :

```
https://www.python.org/downloads/
```

Comment: To start with, ty for the response. Well, i checked and python seems to be installed properly. However, pip is not recognised as an internal or external command. I tried to fix it with the path, as i saw in some tutorials but it didnt work. So pip is the problem.

Comment: Uninstall `Python` through `Revo Uninstaller` and install a recent GA `Python` version.

Comment: Ok, i did it. Could you please suggest what exactly i should download?

Comment: Updated my Answer with the download location. Download and Install recent GA release of `Python`

Answer (score 1):

I'm on VS Code in Windows 10, and here's how I solved it.

You need to pay attention to where the **Python is located** (in my case),

```
1) C:\Users\_Me_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\
```

and where the **Python looks for libraries/packages**, including the ones installed using **pip** (again, in my case),

```
2) C:\Users\_Me_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\
```

I don't know why these two locations are different (gotta fix it at some point). It seemed that Python was running from the first location, but it was looking for libraries in the second!:/

Anyway, since I have limited experience in Python , I just **copied the `\Lib\site-packages` from the first location** (including selenium folders) **to `\site-packages` in second one** in hopes of solving the issue, which worked out for me!

#### How to check for there locations

1) Open Python CLI, typed the following command:

```
which python
```

2) Open Python CLI, typed the following commands (From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59411635/6668976)):

```
>>> import site
>>> site.USER_SITE
```

### EDIT

Since this seems a temporary solution, I uninstalled Python and reinstalled it again in a proper directory (other than the default install directory), and now `which python` and `which pip` point to the same folder! Problem solved!

Comment: This question is old but it may help some people so thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If these solutions did not work for you, try looking into which Python interpreter your IDE is using (in my case I was using VSCode - you can find the interpreter in the bottom bar). Worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to copy all files of "**venv**" Lib, Scripts, Selenium and other folder into your main project folder.
This issue occur as pycharm directly take from virtual environment venv.

Hope this will resolve your problem :)