# how to install Selenium WebDriver in macOS High Seirra?

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio

I have followed this instructions: 
https://www.utest.com/articles/selenium-setup-on-a-mac-and-configuring-selenium-webdriver-on-mac-os

But when I tried `mvn test`, I get an error:

```
sh-3.2# mvn test
sh: mvn: command not found
sh-3.2#
```

Then, I tried to download this as well: 
http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

The file, `selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar` is not installing. Does nothing when I double click it.

I also downloaded Katalon Studio, works well in iOS. It also supports windows and linux, but our boss said, use Selenium only because we already have test cases built in Selenium.

So, is there any other way to install Selenium in macOS High Seirra 10.13?

Comment: Use `pip` from `Python`

Comment: @DebanjanB can you give me a link? pleeeaseee

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : no module named selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium)

Comment: @NicEndo im not really sure what im looking for. I think webdriver and IDE are same?