# Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.common' error message

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium version 3.8 with Python3.6 with chromedriver/gekodriver.

whenever I am running :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

I am getting following error message:

```
C:\Users\myname\PycharmProjects\Selenium\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/myname/.PyCharmCE2017.3/config/scratches/scratch_19.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myname/.PyCharmCE2017.3/config/scratches/scratch_19.py", line 2, in <module>  
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.common'  
Process finished with exit code 1
```

but this is not happening every time few scripts are running perfectly fine:

Following are the steps I have followed:

1. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling Selenium using `pip`.
2. I am facing this issue intermittently both in python IDE and PyCharm.

Further more I have not setup environment variable for Selenium, is this a necessary step for importing selenium module?

Comment: I think you have to add the environment variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : no module named selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error message as I have created a file using the same name "selenium". when I removed that file it fixed the issue.