# Selenium / Python - No module named 'org'

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use the Select function in Selenium for Python 3 to help with navigating through the drop down boxes. However, when I try to import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select I get an error message:

"No module named 'org'"

Would appreciate any help on this. I saw there was a similar question posted a few weeks ago but the link to that question is now broken. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : no module named selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path 'org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select' is a Java descriptor. In Python, make sure you have the Python Selenium module installed with `pip install selenium`, and then import it with `import selenium`.

For the Select function specifically, you can import that with the following

`from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select`

Then you'll be able to use it like this:

`select = Select(b.find_element_by_id(....))`