# Unable to install Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to coding I was trying to install Selenium for python and I was trying to use this command on my Mac Terminal sudo pip install -U selenium
and then I got this message

```
The directory '/Users/ag/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/ag/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting selenium
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/selenium/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for selenium
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me with this

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : no module named selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium)

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used selenium before but I think it work on your computer. 
Try this,

```
$sudo pip install selenium
```

or

```
$sudo easy_install selenium
```

or

```
$sudo brew install selenium
```