# Opening firefox using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I just installed selenium with pip like

```
pip install selenium
```

and installed

```
geckidriver.exe
```

and put it in

```
C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox
```

where my

```
firefox.exe
```

is in.

But when I run a code

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

it returns

```
C:\Users\asd\PycharmProjects\tomato\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/asd/Downloads/pycharmprojects/tomato/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/asd/Downloads/pycharmprojects/tomato/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Firefox'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm using python3 in anaconda3(32bit), on windows7(64bit).

What did I wrong?

Comment: Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium/48269228#48269228

Comment: @DebanjanB I followed the answer, my python is `python3.6.1`, pip is fine, selenium is `3.11.0`. but when I open `pycharm` and run that code, same result came out.

Comment: Can you try to execute the commands one by one through the _CLI_ and update the question with the results (error stack trace if any)?

Answer (score 0):

Before start firefox, you need set the path where the binary is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```