# AttributeError Issue: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: there is no chrome module present under webdriver]I have just started Selenium using Python. And I'm facing the Attribute error issue.

- Have Installed Python 3.6.5 and installed the latest selenium
  packages(selenium-3.11.0)
- Have also added Scripts and Python folder path in the Environment
  variable:**PATH**.
- Downloaded the chromedriver.exe and have added the
  respective file path into the environment variable.

But while running the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("E:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
```

It's throwing the following error:

```
C:\Users\Sooraj\venv\firstpgm\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Sooraj/PycharmProjects/Selenium/First.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sooraj/PycharmProjects/Selenium/First.py", line 2, in 
<module>
driver=webdriver.Chrome("E:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Tried all the other solutions provided here in Stack Overflow like uninstalling and reinstalling Python and upgrading the selenium.But was of no help.

The code was run using PyCharm IDE but when run using IDLE it's working fine.

Could find the folders like firefox,chrome,safari,phantomjs,android etc..under Sitepackages -> selenium -> webdriver.But not sure why it is still showing "Webdriver has no attribute chrome"

The above screenshot attached. Shows no module chrome() under webdriver

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : no module named selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium)

Answer (score 7):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

This is the correct way how to write that code, also if u want to use firefox or something else then change chrome to firefox ... also read 1st a documentation and look for some examples, then put it here if u find nothing

Also use pip install selenium !

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the file you recently created. I am facing same issue when i come to this thread and nothing worked for me. I just deleted my recent file and everything works fine :-)

Before creating new python file selenium work fine. it start showing this error when i create new python file in same folder. When i delete the file , everything work fine as before.

Comment: This just happened to me. Why does adding a .py file in the same directory break selenium?

Answer (score 1):

you should write it like this : `browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")` and please make sure that you have Google Chrome installed on your system.

Comment: I tried your input.
chromedriver.exe is already downloaded. and i have added the path in the environment variable . But still it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Try using following command instead

```
driver = webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver(executable_path='E:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
```

Reference: Official document https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver

Comment: I tried your input . But still the error persist.... Should I degrade my python version?

Answer (score 1):

first check google chrome version of your system by using this in URL   `chrome://version/`

then download chrome driver from below mention website according to chrome version
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

then type this in pycharm or sublime text

```
import selenium

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver(executable_path='C:/drivers/chromedriver_win32 (1)/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

and RUN, surely it works

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7: Pycharm IDE version 2018.1.2
Navigate to

Project Name->venv

Open pyenv.cfg

Change

```
include-system-site-packages = false
```

to

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your filename,  it is not be special name. for example selectors.py

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that the question is two years old. As you gain reputation you'll be able to leave comments, but please do not use the answer feature to leave comments.

Answer (score 0):

**use this and then hit invoke**

> from selenium import webdriver
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=yourpath\chromedriver.exe")

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31230607)

Answer (score 0):

Well what you can do is to consider this official page [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/#three-ways-to-use-drivers)

> Three Ways to Use Drivers...

The first way works well.
For this you have to install webdrivermanager

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

and then

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

[github link for more](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager)

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems with Pycharm.

Go to Python Packages which would be displayed at the bottom line[Pycharm Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMsE2.png)

There search for selenium and install from there if not installed. Once installation is done rerun the script

If issue persist try to add chromedriver.exe file in C:\Python310\Scripts folder and check once

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver(executable_path='/Users/yatin/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

- this worked perfectly fine in pycharm.
  Note: you must have already installed the selenium package from the interpreter

and also match the current chrome version and chrome driver you are downloading, should be same version.

though this command will work but this is depricated so here is new one:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service_obj = Service("/Users/yatin/Downloads/chromedriver")

driver = webdriver.chrome(service=service_obj)

driver.get("www.netflix.com")
```

Comment: Please use the code highlighting when using code in your answer. It improves readability

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and we solved it!! I installed the newest version of python which is 3.9.
I ran it and it yelled at me for selenium.
So I went into command prompt and did :

```sh
pip install selenium
```

It installed selenium. I ran it, and it worked.