# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome' Python3

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use selenium for a project and I have looked at other questions, but can't seem to find a fix. The problem that PyCharm is throwing is in the title. Everything I need is installed(Selenium) - version 3.12.0, I have tried this on my laptop and desktop to see if something was missing, but it didn't help. Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'
```

Code trial:

```
from selenium import webdriver
Browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'''C:\Users\allen\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\TempState\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver''')
```

Comment: remove the extra spaces before parens

Comment: Can you update the question with the error stack trace?

Comment: @DebanjanB Put it in the question. Can you tell me what is happening, and why its not running?

Comment: Is `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>` the complete line in the _Traceback_ or you have trimmed it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this **code** :

```
from selenium import webdriver  

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe')  
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

**Note** :  `D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe` , you should provide the full path of chrome driver here.

Comment: How did you configure selenium 3.12.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to cross check the location of `chromedriver` binary. As per your code trial the following location doesn't appears to be the actual location of `chromedriver` binary which is as follows:

```
C:\Users\allen\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\TempState\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver
```

- While passing the *path* of the *ChromeDriver* you need to mention the *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* i.e. the *absolute path* within single quotes (`''`) separated through single forward slash (`\`) along with the raw (`r`) switch.
- As you are using *Windows OS*, you need to add the extension of the *ChromeDriver* binary (`.exe`) at the end.
- Try to avoid names of common builtin variables e.g. *Browser* to avoid cyclic dependencies.
- Effectively the line of code will be:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\allen\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\TempState\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turns out I didn't have the Python 3 version of the Selenium library installed.

After I ran the following command as admin the above code worked:

```
pip3 install -U selenium
```

Answer (score 0):

selenium-4.17.2 will automatically download and install the drivers.
So why don't you upgrade to the latest version and try this code instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url="some_url")
```

I received the same error with the above code, and then I found this dude's comment [Sanaa Ullah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57744075/16512342), and it worked. Later on, I understood that, that error was for the file's naming. I changed `typing.py` to `speed_typing.py` and it ran smoothly as time.

Comment: The question is specifically about Selenium 3