# 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

i was learing selenium and everyting was working just find, I made a new file called `typing.py` and it contained the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.livechat.com/typing-speed-test/#/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url=url)
```

and then, out of blue, came this error all of a sudden:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome' (most likely due to a circular import). Did you mean: 'chrome'?
```

I searched through internet, all solutions were indicating that selenium couldnt find the chrome driver app, and that I should provide with it; but that was not the case for me, since it was working just fine until a minute a go.

### then I found this dude's comment [Sanaa Ullah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57744075/16512342), upon following his instruction, at my surprise, it worked.
**But whyyy!!**
the directory was like this:

```
selenium
│   .env
│   amazon.py
│   cookie.py
│   linkedin.py
│   main.py
│   typing.py
│   test.py
│
└───__pycache__
        typing.cpython-312.pyc
```

### And my question is, why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your python file `typing.py` is name-clashing with the `typing.py` module in [`wsproto`](https://github.com/python-hyper/wsproto/tree/main/src/wsproto) package which is a dependency of `selenium` that gets installed with selenium (inspect `pip freeze` to see `wsproto` is a dependency and gets installed with selenium, thus its `typing.py` module gets added to the path). Hence, the `AttributeError` message detecting a circular import.

As to "Why?" deleting your `typing.py` fixes the issue, it is no longer clashing with `wsproto`'s `typing.py` module.

Comment: NAME-CLASHING; I'll have to keep that in mind.