# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.firefox'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I was just getting started with selenium. My book asked me to install Firefox so I did. ( I have installed Selenium)  Then it told me to run this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

I run into an error which states:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.firefox'
```

This is somewhat weird becuase when i run `help(selenium)`, it shows:

```
PACKAGE CONTENTS
common (package)
webdriver (package)
```

What should I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Have you downloaded webdriver?

Comment: @James I am using Anaconda Navigator and selenium comes preinstalled in it. Do i need to install it?

Comment: Check selenium and also download the firefox webdriver...also look at this post too...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147660/importerror-no-module-named-selenium

Comment: It still won't work :(

Comment: show the code you are running

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I have shown it already! Is there anything else you'd like to know?