# Selenium webdriver imports correct in the Python shell, but not when I write a script

Tags: python, selenium

So I am trying to use the selenium webdriver in a python script as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Now this is all fine and dandy when I do it within the python shell, but if I write it into a script it tells me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/gvasquez/Scripts/viaUpdate.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'.
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: did you pip install Selenium? Try some of the troubleshooting steps from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147660/importerror-no-module-named-selenium)

Comment: `from Selenium import webdriver` Capitalization matters.  Why are you using a capital `S`?

Comment: @JohnGordon this is good to point out. I grabbed the wrong traceback, as that was an error I had noticed when I first wrote the code. This is the current error with proper capitalization:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gvasquez\Scripts\viaUpdate.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'`

Comment: What command do you use to run the Python shell, and what command do you use to run the script?

Comment: @GrahamVasquez please update your question with the correct traceback

Comment: @JosephRajchwald Yep, when I run `pip list` I see `selenium   3.141.0`

Comment: @JohnGordon I have added my scripts folder to my path so I just run `viaUpdate.py`. This works for all my other scripts but if you have something I should change I'm game.

Comment: @wpercy Updated questions with correct traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I feel really dumb, but it looks like all I had to do was run it with the python command prior to the filename:

`PS C:\User\username\scripts> python viaUpdate.py`

instead of `PS C:\User\username\scripts> viaUpdate.py`

Thanks for the help.