# "No module named 'selenium'" when running on ubuntu (Python/Selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-18.04

When I attempt to run my Selenium code on ubuntu, I am receiving the following error:

> from selenium import webdriver
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named 'selenium'

Comment: Can you clarify what your Selenium installation looks like? i.e., did you run 'pip install selenium' on the machine, etc? What setup steps for ubuntu did you follow?

Comment: i upgrade python2.7 to python 3.5. also install pip

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Following commands will done the job.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
$ sudo pip install selenium
```

If you still have problem then follow the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html). You can also check related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147660/importerror-no-module-named-selenium).

Comment: The directory '/home/workland/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/workland/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Why You Getting This Error:

Well Python Says There is no selenium installed in python

If You Want To Use Selenium You Need To Download Install With Terminal:

Here is The Way You Can Try:

if Your `pip3` is recognized Try This:

```
pip3 install selenium
```

if you get this error:

Command Not Found

Something Like That

Try This:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install selenium
```