# What would be the intractable XPATH / element to type in text into a Google Doc?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I am running a code in Python that is to open a Google Doc and type in a certain set of combinations for a set length. I have the code that allows me to go to my Google Docs and open up a new document, however when I try to find the XPATH or element to type in text into the doc itself, I keep getting an error that says:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Currently, I keep trying to see if the XPATH is `//*[@id="kix-appview"]/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/span[2]/span/span` *could be shorter but I don't care about how large the file size is*. If anyone is able to help out or happens to know the XPATH off the top of your head, all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below xpath :

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='kix-appview']/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/span[2]/span/span")))
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: I keep getting the same error. I am trying to type in text into the document, but every time my code gets to the point where I am to type in text into the document, I get the same error as above.

Comment: share you link if possible

Comment: if you are facing error ImportError: No module named selenium then refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147660/importerror-no-module-named-selenium

Comment: I am not having an import error. I used codepad to show my code since I am running my code using Geany. I am not using Github to store my code or anything like that, I just am using Geany to run my code and to store it as a .py file. My error when I run the code using Geany is element not interactable.

Comment: So if i want to check your element on your site  :: //*[@id='kix-appview']/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/span[2]/span/span

Comment: The element is on this website if that is what you are asking.https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UFZbhyiE9H7AFdYH7M9D73wCdt89I83Yxb2qAsoUHx4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you trying to handle arrow key please hightligh your element in the screenshot