# Selenium issues with driver

Tags: python, selenium

So selenium giving me issues I'm either getting no module named selenium or webdriver not defined

I've reinstalled selenium idk what to do?

[image: Here's an image of what I see]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'selenium'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147660/importerror-no-module-named-selenium)

Comment: Can you please add some more information regarding what you are using? Environment, Python/Selenium versions, and definitely include the error that you see. If you can, please provide some of the code/script you are using to run it, and the setup script if you have any. (just make sure you replace any sensitive information with **** like passwords, etc)

Comment: Please do not attach your error as image but append it as text in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Selenium using pip.

```
pip install selenium
```

Or, you can check in the Python Library whether selenium is installed in it or not

Comment: I installed in multiple times still havent found a solution