# How to solve No module named 'selenium' in VS code?

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, path

How to solve No module named 'selenium' in VS code?

**Module to be used**

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time,sys,csv,pyautogui
```

However, the following error occurred.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'`

**I tried in VS code to solve this error.**

A similar situation with me, stack overflow the resolution, but failed.

-> [ImportError: No module named 'selenium'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147660/importerror-no-module-named-selenium)

```
1.pip install selenium
2.conda install selenium
```

[image]
-> select Python 3.8.5 -64bit(conda)

> how to solved ModuleNotFoundError?
> help me..

**comment update(programandoconro)**
[image]

-> An error still occurs.

**comment update(Prophet)**

[image]

-> An error still occurs.

Comment: I see you installed Selenium but can't see you set the system PATH while this is the main problem here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both answers above might work but it is better to create a [virtual environment](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/#:%7E:text=At%20its%20core%2C%20the%20main,dependencies%20every%20other%20project%20has.) and install your dependencies in there. Since you're already using Anaconda, I'll list the steps below.

You can create a virtual environment with Anaconda:

1. `conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda`
2. `source activate yourenvname`

You can find more info how to setup your `environment` [here](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/)

Comment: Based on the link, we created a virtual environment and installed selenium completely.

Answer (score 4):

Please try `python3 -m pip install selenium`.
This will allow you to use the current active version of Python you are using.

### Update:

I saw that you are using an `.ipynb` extension. I am not an expert in those kind of environments but I would try to run `!python3 -m pip install selenium` inside the file (not the terminal). This only the first time, then you can comment that line. Please try that.

Answer (score 2):

Best Solution: Worked for me.

Issue: The version of python you are using does not have "Selenium" in its root folder. If you are using python 3.8 for instance, you are missing Selenium in "Lib\site-packages" directory.

1. Go to your C:\ drive and locate all your Python folders (python version #s)
2. In each folder go to "Lib\site-packages" and see if you have "Selenium" installed.
3. If its in the folder of python version that you are not using, just copy the folders in the correct python version folder in "Lib\site-packages" path.

This should do it....

Answer (score 1):

You're might run a virtual environment and installed selenium in your default python environment. If so try to install it into the local one.

Answer (score 0):

If you already installed Selenium by `pip install selenium` or by any other way and still see that error I guess you are missing a system PATH set to Python or Selenium folder in your machine.
So just add those folders locations to you machine PATH as described [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-install-selenium-webdriver-on-any-computer-with-python/) or any other place.

Comment: I tried to install it, but there is still an error.
`Can you tell me how to do PATH SETTING?`

Comment: I see you are using windows. So just ask google `how to set path in windows` it's quite simple