# Can't set up ruby-selenium Webdriver on Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, homebrew

I've been using selenium IDE at work. Now we have decided to use Selenium webdriver with Ruby. I'm totally confused about how to set up my Mac, *Mac Pro Yosemite 10.10.5*.

In my terminal, I ran these commands:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
$ brew install ruby
  ==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1: 464 files, 18M
==> Installing ruby
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ruby-2.2.3.yosemite.bottle.100.0%
==> Pouring ruby-2.2.3.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3: 1080 files, 20M

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]

$ sudo gem install selenium-webdriver
   Done installing documentation for websocket, ffi, childprocess, rubyzip, multi_json, selenium-webdriver after 25 seconds
6 gems installed
```

I exported the script recorded from IDE into a Ruby script with: export as `ruby/rspec/webdriver`. I saved my example script as `Exam.rb` in documents.

When I run `rspec Exam.rb`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/xxxx/Documents/Exam.rb (LoadError)     
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'        
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'        
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'     
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'       
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'      
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'      
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'       
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'     
    from /usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `load'      
    from /usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

And when I cheked the ruby version:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

Comment: did you check this Link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868743/how-to-install-selenium-webdriver-on-mac-os

Comment: @SankarRaj Chked.  Actually, my prob is diff. I get errors when trying to open a ruby script. So i think i have gone wrong with my set up

Comment: could you please include the 'Exam.rb' file?

Comment: also a few things.  use rvm for ruby installs instead of the system ruby, and don't sudo install gems, that can be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

After you have ruby (I recommend **R**uby**V**ersion**M**anager or **rbenv**)

You need to install the gem **selenium-webdriver**

And after that, you need a [driver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) to control the desired browser, in my case I install [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/), it's just a binary(I added it to my home and edit the environment variable $PATH with the path to the binary) And thats all everything is working, you can run this litlle script to verify it:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com"
element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
element.send_keys "Hello Selenium WebDriver!"
element.submit
puts driver.title
```

Consult this book: [Selenium WebDriver Recipes](http://leanpub.com/selenium-recipes-in-ruby) in ruby of Zhimin Zhan